# Can't get Calculator JApplet GUI to show buttons in an orderly fashion

Tags: java, swing, applet, awt

I have been trying to get my JApplet to show all the buttons needed for a calculator applet in an orderly fashion, but I can't seem to get them to all be the same size and display right under each other. Should I use different a different layout or change the entire design? Thanks in advance.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class MyCalc extends JApplet implements ActionListener{

/**
 * 
 */
protected static final long serialVersionUID = 3169756252830354073L;

private JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
private JMenu edit = new JMenu("Edit");
private JMenu view = new JMenu("View");
private JMenu help = new JMenu("Help");

//Instantiated all JPanels used in this Applet
private JPanel[] rows = {new JPanel(), new JPanel(), new JPanel(), 
        new JPanel(), new JPanel(), new JPanel(), new JPanel()};

JTextField calc = new JTextField(1);

private JButton[] buttons = {new JButton("Backspace"), new JButton("CE"), new JButton("C"), 
        new JButton("MC"), new JButton("7"), new JButton("8"), new JButton("9"), 
        new JButton("/"), new JButton("sqrt"), new JButton("MR"), new JButton("4"), 
        new JButton("5"), new JButton("6"), new JButton("*"), new JButton("%"), 
        new JButton("MS"), new JButton("1"), new JButton("2"), new JButton("3"), 
        new JButton("-"), new JButton("1/x"), new JButton("M+"), new JButton("0"), 
        new JButton("+/-"), new JButton("."), new JButton("+"), new JButton("=")};

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if(e.getSource() == buttons[0])
    {

    }

}

public void init()
{
    setName("Calculator Applet");
    menuBar.add(edit);
    menuBar.add(view);
    menuBar.add(help);
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    rows[0].setLayout(new BoxLayout(rows[0], BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    getContentPane();
    add(rows[0]);
    setSize(300, 200);

    calc.setText("0.");
    calc.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        rows[2].add(buttons[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 3; i < 9; i++)
    {
        rows[3].add(buttons[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 9; i < 15; i++)
    {
        rows[4].add(buttons[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 15; i < 21; i++)
    {
        rows[5].add(buttons[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 21; i < 26; i++)
    {
        rows[6].add(buttons[i]);
    }

    rows[1].add(calc);
    rows[1].setLayout(new GridLayout());
    rows[2].setLayout(new GridLayout());
    rows[0].add(rows[1]);
    rows[0].add(rows[2]);

    for(int i = 3; i < 7; i++)
    {
        rows[0].add(rows[i]);
        rows[i].setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect it to look like?

Comment: I would like the first three buttons to be above all the other buttons, and then rows of six buttons each, and all of those buttons directly under each other instead rooked like they are now. Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "but I can't seem to get them to all be the same size and display right under each other."

Generally this screams out `GridLayout`. Instead of using two `BoxLayout` (one vertical and one horizinal) just use a `GridLayout(4, 6)` (for the number buttons). Keep in mind though that the size of the buttons will be the size of the largest button (which is sqrt).

Also I'd recommend staying away from keeping your panels in an array like you are doing. It's difficult to follow the flow of how you want to add everything. Give your panels (and all components for that matter) meaningful names that are self-documenting.

For general knowledge on layout managers, check out [Laying out Component Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

I refactored your code to be able to run it as an applet or as a standalone frame. I also wrapped all the components in a panel and set the layout manager of the content pane to `GridBagLayout`, so everything does get screwed up if you resize the frame

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MyCalc extends JApplet implements ActionListener {

    /**
 * 
 */
    protected static final long serialVersionUID = 3169756252830354073L;

    private JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    private JMenu edit = new JMenu("Edit");
    private JMenu view = new JMenu("View");
    private JMenu help = new JMenu("Help");

    // Instantiated all JPanels used in this Applet
    //private JPanel[] rows = { new JPanel(), new JPanel(), new JPanel(),
    //      new JPanel(), new JPanel(), new JPanel(), new JPanel() };

    JTextField calc = new JTextField(1);

    private JButton[] buttons = { new JButton("Backspace"), new JButton("CE"),
            new JButton("C"), new JButton("MC"), new JButton("7"),
            new JButton("8"), new JButton("9"), new JButton("/"),
            new JButton("sqrt"), new JButton("MR"), new JButton("4"),
            new JButton("5"), new JButton("6"), new JButton("*"),
            new JButton("%"), new JButton("MS"), new JButton("1"),
            new JButton("2"), new JButton("3"), new JButton("-"),
            new JButton("1/x"), new JButton("M+"), new JButton("0"),
            new JButton("+/-"), new JButton("."), new JButton("+"),
            new JButton("=") };

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == buttons[0]) {

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                MyCalc calc = new MyCalc();
                calc.init();
                frame.add(calc);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public void init() {
        setName("Calculator Applet");
        menuBar.add(edit);
        menuBar.add(view);
        menuBar.add(help);
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        Container contentPane = getContentPane();

        calc.setText("0.");
        calc.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        JPanel topButtonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            topButtonPanel.add(buttons[i]);
        }

        JPanel numberButtonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 6));
        for (int i = 3; i < 26; i++) {
            numberButtonPanel.add(buttons[i]);
        }

        JPanel centerWrapper = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        centerWrapper.add(calc, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        centerWrapper.add(topButtonPanel);
        centerWrapper.add(numberButtonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        contentPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        contentPane.add(centerWrapper);
    }
}
```